# InvalidStatusCode: server rejected WebSocket connection: HTTP 401

Tags: python, infura, pending-transactions, ethereum-classic

I am trying to subscribe to pending transactions on the Ethereum blockchain using this tutorial from Infura: https://docs.infura.io/tutorials/ethereum/subscribe-to-pending-transactions

When I try to execute the .py file in Terminal it reads:

'''
websockets.exceptions.InvalidStatusCode: server rejected WebSocket connection: HTTP 401
'''

I am very unfamiliar with Python and Infura websockets. What is the problem with my code and how can I correct it?

Comment: Hi, make sure to add the WebSocket endpoint in the variable `infura_ws_url`. It worked as expected for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GM, Developer Relations Lead at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) here.

Assuming you're using the full code snippet provided in that article, this error stems from an attempt to open a WebSocket connection on an invalid endpoint- this most likely means that the URL you're using in `async with connect(URL) as ws:` is not a valid WebSocket endpoint~ which could be the result of not using the right endpoint authentication (the string that goes into `<YOUR_API_KEY>`)

As a side note, the code provided in this article works for me with a Chainstack Elastic Node.